# Velocity Removing New Line (Apache Velocity 2.0)

Tags: velocity, apache-velocity

Recently we migrated our application from Velocity 1.7 to 2.0. But after the migration. I see a strange problem, that the output is chomping new lines and merging lines. This happens when we do a `parseTemplate()` call.

For Example, here is the piece of code that is causing the problem.

```
#if ($bvoipData && $bvoipConfigType == "TDM")
    call rsvp-sync
    !
    dial-peer cor custom
    !
    #parseTemplate ("IPFlex/VoiceDialPeer.vm")
    sip-ua
    .
    .
    .
    .

#end
```

With the previous version, the output came in like:

```
dial-peer hunt 1

!
sip-ua

 retry invite 2

 no cdp run

!
```

But with Velocity 2.0, I get the output as:

```
dial-peer hunt 1

!sip-ua

 retry invite 2

 no cdp run

!
```

I would expect the sip-ua to show up in a new line, rather it just merges it to the previous line.

The line:

```
dial-peer hunt 1

!
```

comes from the template `IPFlex/VoiceDialPeer.vm`.

Not sure if there is some extra configuration that was introduced as a part of the 2.0 release that I probably missed. Any pointers on this would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Velocity 2.0 introduces the notion of [*space gobbling*](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.3/developer-guide.html#space-gobbling).

I guess you would need to add

```
parser.space_gobbling = bc # stands for 'backward-compatible'
```

to your configuration.

More generally, to maximize backward compatibility with 1.7, you would need to set the following configuration:

```
# No automatic conversion of methods arguments
introspector.conversion_handler.class = none

# Use backward compatible space gobbling
parser.space_gobbling = bc

# Have #if($foo) only returns false if $foo is false or null
directive.if.empty_check = false

# Allow '-' in identifiers (since 2.1)
parser.allow_hyphen_in_identifiers = true

# Enable backward compatibility mode for Velocimacros
velocimacro.enable_bc_mode = true

# When using an invalid reference handler, also include quiet references (since 2.2)
event_handler.invalid_references.quiet = true

# When using an invalid reference handler, also include null references (since 2.2)
event_handler.invalid_references.null = true

# When using an invalid reference handler, also include tested references (since 2.2)
event_handler.invalid_references.tested = true
```

as stated on the [*upgrading*](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.3/upgrading.html#upgrading-from-velocity-21-to-velocity-22) page.